# Correctly reinstalling Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I had trouble installing Angular Material with the Angular CLI, so I installed it through npm and then added it with the ng command.
The issue is that I couldn't select a custom theme and now it's hard to configure it correctly. Is there a way to reinstall it completely so I can get the CLI configuration?

Comment: Do you want to select another theme or reinstall it completely ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select a prebuilt theme, just go to your angular.json file, then change styles section with whatever you need.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "styles.scss",
],
```

Check node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes for a list of available prebuilt themes.

If you want to use a custom theme, i recommend using https://materialtheme.arcsine.dev/, they did a great job, then add your own theme file to styles list:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.scss",
  "src/theme.scss", // for example
],
```

**UPDATE:**

Concerning path to styles is: **"projects.[your_project_name].architect.build.options.styles"**

Now concerning theme, you can use a prebuilt theme or make your own, defining palettes from scratch, typography ...etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue I see here is that I will end up with redundant css wouln't I? Should I remove the prebuilt theme?

Comment: Also it didn't work for serving the project since options doesn't have the styles property